# .Net send keys as keyvalue

Tags: .net, keystroke

I have a very short question. My laptop activates its touchpad everytime i log in. This annoys me because I want to use my mouse only. I want to write a very small application (which I will add as scheduled tasks). This small application should send FN + F6 key combination and close itself. I have some experience with VB.Net but I don't know how to send keyvalue. I have captured this combination with a textbox.keydown:
KeyCode: None
KeyData: LButton, OemClear
KeyValue: 255

How can I send the KeyValue with .Net?

By the way I have found this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fn_key

In that wikipedia article it says that FN key is interpreted in the microcontroller of the keyboard. However only lenovo gives the opportunity to catch this, as it processes this in the CPU. But in order to this I need to change some settings in BIOS etc. etc. Need to read more.

Comment: Please at least try a simple search first before posting a question. In this case, try `[vb.net] send key` (including the brackets).

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear in my title but if you read my message it is about sending a special key stroke "FN + F6". FN key is somehow different from other keys. I have made a search but didn't find anything. SendKeys class of .Net is not capable to do this and actually seems to be very limited. But I have captured this combination as KeyCode, KeyData and KayValue. Now I can send it as KeyValue or KeyData but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you FN + F6 does but I am pretty sure you can just send what you need via the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method